# Ordering cell rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this sort faster and better?

```
function OrderBy(a,b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

SortBy = function($th) {
    var $tbody = $th.closest('tbody');
    var $table = $tbody.parent();
    $tbody.detach();
    $('#Processing').show('fast',function () {
        var column = $th.index();
        var rows = $tbody.find('tr').get();
        rows.sort(function(rowA,rowB) {
            var keyA = $(rowA).children('td').eq(column).text();
            var keyB = $(rowB).children('td').eq(column).text();
            return OrderBy(keyA,keyB);
        });
        $.each(rows, function(index,row) {
            $tbody.append(row);
        });
        $table.append($tbody);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the cell texts before sorting, so that it doesn't have to happen repeatedly in the order function:

```
    var rowsWithText = $tbody.find('tr').map(function() {
      return {
        row: this, 
        text: $(this).children('td').eq(column).text()
      };
    });
    rowsWithText.sort(function(rowA, rowB) {
        return OrderBy(rowA.text, rowB.text);
    });
    $.each(rowsWithText, function(index,row) {
        $tbody.append(row.row);
    });
```

Comment: I've seen the map function before, but haven't paid any attention to it. I'll check it out.  Thanks!